# How to delete list of categories?

Tags: php, wordpress, list, html-lists, categories

my last question on my website http://velvetart.net. When I´m seeing single.php (http://velvetart.net/2013/11/new-onliner-shakira-online-net/) categories are here messy. When I check HTML, it showing that categories are in unordered list.

```
<ul class="post-categories">
<li><a href="http://velvetart.net/category/ordered/" rel="category tag" tiptitle="View all posts in Ordered">Ordered</a></li>
<li><a href="http://velvetart.net/category/wp-themes/" rel="category tag" tiptitle="View all posts in Wordpress Themes">Wordpress Themes</a></li></ul>
```

how can I delete this list? I tried this in functions.php and category-template.php, i delete all list from these files, but still showing categories as list.. :/

I have this in my category-template.php

```
<div class="post-categories">
```

but in HTML, it shows like

```
<ul class="post-categories">
```

Does anyone know where can I change this? Thank you :)

Comment: you can see my category-template.php here http://www.mediafire.com/view/09ab5mty9kcocos/category-template.php

Comment: You should locate the code that changes `<div>` to `<ul>`.

Comment: @geomagas and how this code looks like? :O

Comment: It doesn't look like anything specific, you'll have to read it and understand what it does, and _then_ decide for yourself if it's what you're looking for. This kind of stuff can be written in a bunch of different ways. The only certain thing is that it will be... well... _in php!_

Comment: @geomagas it works! thank you :) do you want to write it as answer, and I can confirm it? :)

Comment: There's no answer, only pointers. Thus the comments. But you could [provide your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) as to the steps you took to solve it. Trust me, it _will_ help someone some day!